# What should I do for creating activities with the same layouts?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have some `Acitivity` with a `ListView`.

I want that after clicking the `ListView` item there should be new `Activity` with the same type of layout contains another info(e.g.`ListView`) related to the clicked item.

I have known that there is not way to create dynamically `Activities`.
What should I do to be able to go from one Layout to another(by clicking `ListView` items) and should be able to go back in the same back-sequence by back-key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have known that there is not way to create dynamically Activities.
>   What should I do to be able to go from one Layout to another(by
>   clicking ListView items) and should be able to go back in the same
>   back-sequence by back-key?

Why can't you create activities dynamically? You can easily create a new one from your ListView onclick listener

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

         //Based on the position of the clicked item create a new activity with the position id
         Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, newActivity.this);
         intent.putExtra("id", position);
         startActivity(intent);
   }
};
```

And now in the newActivity you would check what is the passed id by doing

```
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        theId = bundle.getInt("id");

            //Now do something based on that id
```

Pressing on the back key from the new activity should take you back to the previous one

Comment: Every next activity must be the same as the previous. There are undefined quantities of (nasted) onItemclicks.

Comment: It is better:  Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, currentActivity.class);

Answer (score 0):

You can use A Fragment to implements your ListView:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html
then you can simply replace the current ListFragment with a new one by using the FragmentManager class and the FragmentTransation class. In this way the FragmentManager will take care of replacing the new ListFragment with the old one when you press the back button.
Be careful since if you use ListFragment your SDK target must be 11 or more. If this is a concern for you, you can use the class Fragment from the support library putting inside it a ListView. FragmentManager and FragmentTransation are also part of the support library.